# python mqtt to stop subscribing for 20 seconds after particular payload has been received

Tags: python, mqtt, paho, timedelay

I have my python script that I connect to my mqtt broker and subscribe to a topic. When I receive the payload "hello" the script executes an action in my case prints "good". What I am trying to do is, when the payload "hello" has been received I am trying to execute an action for 20 seconds and in that time I do not want the script to detect any other payloads i.e. it should unsubscribe from the topic (I thought this was a better way but I am open to suggestions).

I do not want any payloads to be detected in my topic during those 20 seconds delay. In my case (script) what happens is that in those 20 seconds delay the script is still subscribed to the topic and after 20 seconds it prints "good" again. I do not want that to happen; instead after the 20 seconds things should resume normally i.e. another "hello" is detected .

Here is my code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqttClient
import time

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):

    if rc == 0:

        print("Connected to broker")

        global Connected                #Use global variable
        Connected = True                #Signal connection

    else:

        print("Connection failed")

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
##
    if  message.payload == "hello":
        client.unsubscribe("home/OpenMQTTGateway/433toMQTT")
        print("good")
        time.sleep(20)


Connected = False   #global variable for the state of the connection

broker_address= "192.168.0.6"  #Broker address
port = 1883                         #Broker port
user = "123456"                    #Connection username
password = "abcdef"            #Connection password

client = mqttClient.Client("Python")               #create new instance
client.username_pw_set(user, password=password)    #set username and password
client.on_connect= on_connect                      #attach function to callback
client.on_message= on_message                      #attach function to callback
client.connect(broker_address,port,60) #connect
client.subscribe("home/OpenMQTTGateway/433toMQTT") #subscribe
client.loop_forever() #then keep listening forever
```

**UPDATE:**

@Mike Organek

What i now want is that after it prints good.. I need it to print bad until another hello is published in the topic and it prints good for another 20 seconds so the cycle continues. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: What messages are arriving in this time?  Do you need it to stop processing messages for twenty seconds?

Comment: No so your solution is fine all I am trying to add is a else statement which after printing "good" and holding it for 20 seconds I need the script to do another thing which is print "bad"  if "hello" in the payload has not been published. I hope that make sense ?

Comment: I have added more code at the bottom.  It would have been a lot easier to understand if you had told me your use case.  It looks like you want messages to be rejected as `bad`  and then, after getting `hello`, to ignore all messages for twenty seconds and then begin processing other messages.  The code I pasted will restart the twenty-second ignore period every time it receives a `hello`.

Comment: OK so what i am trying to do is this. I have a RF motion sensor that publishes a six digit code in the topic that I have subscribed to in my python code. Once the six digit code is published I will a nt my monitor to turn on for 5 mintues instead of printing good. After the monitor is turned on for 5 minutes I want it to turn off until another 6 digit code is published in the topic i.e. another motion is detected. So essentially in the if statement I need an else statement to turn the monitor off in my example I was printing bad. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Understood.  Does the updated code in my answer handle your use case?

Comment: @Mike Organek the updated code doesn't print "bad" at all

Comment: @Mike Organek did you get my message buddy?

Comment: It prints `bad` on any message other than `hello` received before the first `hello`.

Comment: @Mike Organek I tried the code but it doesn't print "bad" I think because you have used if not and also !=

Comment: It prints `bad` for me.  Take the code and change it to whatever you want.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help

Comment: Are you sure it prints `bad` for you? I tried it again and debugged it but I fail to get `bad`. Which code are you using sorry? can you please update your code by stating the latest one. Also I am getting an error  with your code   
`File "main.py", line 29
    print("good", flush=True)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Please see update to my answer.  The code runs just fine here.  I added a transcript from a running session where I was generating messages using `mosquitto_pub` from another shell.

Comment: @Mike Organek so let me understand this. The latest update to your answer contains obviously part of the code without showing the topic, broker etc which I need to add after your answer in my script? Secondly your answer is perfect but I think what you misunderstood is that when "hello" is not published then it should print "bad". Your answer prints bad if it receives anything other than "hello" but essentially what i need is if it does receive hello than it should print "good" for 20 seconds and if it doesn't receive anything than it should print "bad"

Comment: You are on your own.

Comment: `print(f 'Received [{message.payload.decode()}] at {time.time()}, printing "bad"')
                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: can anyone else help please? I suppose the answer to the question was correct however the modification which was required was not understood clearly as seen from my 2nd comment in the comments section **which is print "bad" if "hello" in the payload has not been published.** I suppose @MikeOrganek included in his answer anything other than "hello" is published the code would do something which is misunderstood and not what I meant in my explanation i.e. comment number 2 in the comments section

Answer (score 3):

You really should not be calling sleep in `on_message()`.

The `on_message()` callback runs on the MQTT client network thread, while it is running the client can not publish or receive any other messages, this includes keep alive packets.

As a rule you should do no long running tasks or things that might block in the callback. If you need to do long running tasks then you need to do these on a separate thread.